# Remove public profile and friends list from scope in facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the facebook SDK. Works really nice any very simple.

The scope seems to be working but for some reason it is including unwanted scope like public profile and friends list.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            // console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            window.location = "<?php echo $fb_app_url; ?>"
        });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorise.');
    }
}, { scope: 'user_likes' });
```

I am purely just after likes.

If I use the php sdk I swear this it only includes scope you add. Actually, just tested this and is the same...

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
));
```

Can anyone advise to why this issue is occurring?

Thanks

---

Please see below...

This is what is currently being asked for...

[image]

And this is what I want to see, just likes...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[It's written here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/)  that "These Permissions cannot be revoked in the Login Dialog during the login flow, meaning they are non-optional for Users when logging into your app."

Comment: What do you mean? - I will add a screenshot above of what I mean.

Comment: It means they are always granted when using login dialog.

Comment: Please see above - Yesterday when I was coding this, I 99% sure I saw this second dialog, but this is just a photoshop.

Comment: Yeah but it says 'These Permissions' and in the permissions list below are not 'Public profile' or 'Friends list'? So the scope that I don't want are actually not in the list and can revoked no?

Comment: It can be revoked later yes.. I used FB.getLoginStatus and FB.login if not logged in, asking for publish_actions and it was ok.

Comment: I am so confused. Yesterday it worked without FB.getLoginStatus